# Unhandled Exceptions on Asp.Net AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, elmah

I am using Asp.Net's AJAX implementation and need to do two additional things when an unhandled exception occurs:

- Log any unhandled exceptions using ELMAH
- Return a message back to the page

I am inserting the AJAX script into the page using the following code:

```
        ClientScriptManager cm = Page.ClientScript;
        String cbReference = cm.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg",
            "receiveData", "");
        String callbackScript = "function sendData(arg, context) {" +
            cbReference + "; }";
        cm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
            "sendData", callbackScript, true);
```

How do I configure it so that it also accounts for unhandled exceptions? Btw, ELMAH is already installed on my website and correctly logs exceptions from regular postbacks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into things a little further and it seems that responses are being sent and the exceptions are being logged, but not all of them. I haven't figured out the exact criteria for logging, but exceptions generated by ASP.NET are being logged while exceptions generated by myself are not (ie. create and throw).

Hope this helps someone.